Sending data over ngrok using SIM800L and arduino Uno
Few notes :- i have checked http post request with SIM800L and firebase.its working on firebase but iam getting problem in ngrok.And also i have tested ngrok using postman there also i getting proper response.
i tried enabling/disabling SSL.
Following are arduino logs.
03:41:55.335 -> AT

 03:41:55.454 -> OK
 03:41:56.619 -> AT+CPIN?

 03:41:56.919 -> +CPIN: READY
 03:41:57.350 -> 
 03:41:57.394 -> OK
 03:41:58.530 -> AT+CREG?

 03:41:58.883 -> +CREG: 0,2
 03:41:59.228 -> 
 03:41:59.295 -> OK
 03:42:00.419 -> AT+CGATT?

 03:42:00.801 -> +CGATT: 0
  


 

03:42:02.328 -> AT+CGATT=1

 

03:42:02.696 -> OK
 

03:42:06.845 -> 
 

03:42:06.934 -> Call Ready
 

03:42:07.266 -> 
 

03:42:07.339 -> SMS Ready
 

03:42:07.683 -> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"

 

03:42:08.646 -> OK
 

03:42:11.811 -> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","airtelgprs.com"

 

03:42:12.951 -> OK
 

03:42:16.098 -> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER",""

 

03:42:16.860 -> OK 
03:42:19.981 -> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD",""

03:42:20.701 -> OK
 

03:42:24.848 -> AT+SAPBR=1,1

 

03:42:25.291 -> OK
 

03:42:29.413 -> AT+CEER

 

03:42:29.717 -> +CEER: No Cause
 

03:42:30.239 -> 
 

03:42:30.314 -> OK
 

03:42:31.437 -> AT+SAPBR=2,1

 

03:42:31.905 -> +SAPBR: 1,1,"100.124.71.104"
 

03:42:32.810 -> 
 

03:42:32.841 -> OK
 

03:42:33.992 -> AT+CSQ

 

03:42:34.252 -> +CSQ: 14,0
 

03:42:34.623 -> 
 

03:42:34.662 -> OK
 

03:42:35.807 -> AT+CGATT?

 

03:42:36.175 -> +CGATT: 1
 

03:42:36.491 -> 
 

03:42:36.565 -> OK
 

03:42:37.699 -> AT+HTTPINIT

 

03:42:38.121 -> OK
 

03:42:39.266 -> AT+HTTPSSL=1

 

03:42:39.678 -> OK
 

03:42:40.820 -> AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

 

03:42:41.509 -> OK
 

03:42:45.698 -> AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://b3ca-223-233-86-136.ngrok-free.app/aAT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

 

03:42:50.449 -> OK
AT+HTTPDATA=8,20000

 

03:42:52.225 -> DOWNLOAD
 

03:42:57.576 -> 
 

03:42:57.622 -> OK
 

03:42:57.735 -> AT+HTTPACTION=1

 

03:42:58.284 -> OK
 

03:43:09.420 -> 
 

03:43:09.513 -> +HTTPACTION: 1,606,0
 

03:43:10.136 -> AT+HTTPREAD

 

03:43:10.565 -> OK
 

03:43:11.715 -> AT+HTTPTERM

 

03:43:12.108 -> OK 

Server side code is here**
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Set up Express app
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Middleware to parse URL-encoded data (used by SIM800L for HTTP POST)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Received request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    next();
});
  
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
    const { id, message } = req.body;
    console.log(`Received data: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
    res.status(200).send("Message received successfully!");
});
  

// Simple GET endpoint to check server is working
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is running!");
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Here is arduino code.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const String APN  = "airtelgprs.com";
const String USER = "";
const String PASS = "";

// SoftwareSerial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial sim800l(2, 3); // RX, TX
bool gprsAttached = false; 
bool isGPRSAttached() {
  String response = "";
  sendATCommand("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(2000);

  // Read all the available response
  while (sim800l.available()) {
    char c = sim800l.read();
    response += c;
  }

  // Check if the response contains "+CGATT: 1" indicating GPRS is attached
  Serial.println(response);  // Debugging: Print the full response

  if (response.indexOf("+CGATT: 1") != -1) {
    Serial.println("GPRS is attached.");
    return true;
  } else {
    Serial.println("GPRS is not attached.");
    return false;
  }
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sim800l.begin(9600);

  delay(2000);

  // Check if the module is responding
  sendATCommand("AT+CFUN=1,1");
  delay(6000);
  sendATCommand("AT");                     // Check module
  sendATCommand("AT+CPIN?");               // Check SIM card status
  sendATCommand("AT+CREG?");               // Verify network registration
  sendATCommand("AT+CGATT?");              // Check GPRS attachment

  sendATCommand("AT+CGATT=1");
  delay(3000);  // Ensure the module is attached to the network
 
  sendATCommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\""); // Set connection type
  delay(2000);
  sendATCommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"airtelgprs.com\""); // Set APN
  delay(2000);
  sendATCommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"USER\",\"\""); // Set APN
  delay(2000);
  sendATCommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"PWD\",\"\""); // Set APN
  delay(3000);
  sendATCommand("AT+SAPBR=1,1");           // Enable GPRS
  delay(3000);
  sendATCommand("AT+CEER");           // Enable GPRS
  sendATCommand("AT+SAPBR=2,1");           // Verify GPRS connection

  // Test basic connectivity
  sendATCommand("AT+CSQ");  // Check signal quality
  sendATCommand("AT+CGATT?");  // Check if GPRS is attached

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPINIT");            // Initialize HTTP
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPSSL=1");           // Disable SSL for testing with HTTP
}

void loop() {
  // Define URL and HTTP POST data
 
  String url = "https://b3ca-223-233-86-136.ngrok-free.app/api";  // Replace with ngrok URL (HTTP for testing)
  String postData = "id=tiva1";  // Change the message content

  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  delay(3000);

  // Set URL parameter
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"" + url + "\"");

  // Set Content-Type
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\"");

  // Specify data to be sent
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPDATA=" + String(postData.length()) + ",20000");
  delay(2000); // Wait for the module to be ready to accept data
  sim800l.println("id=tiva1");  // Send POST data
  delay(2000);

  // Start the POST request
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPACTION=1");  // 1 for POST request
  delay(10000); // Wait for the response
 
  // Read the response
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPREAD");

  // Close the HTTP service
  sendATCommand("AT+HTTPTERM");

  delay(60000); // Wait for 1 minute before making the next request
}

void sendATCommand(String command) {
  sim800l.println(command);
  delay(1000);
  while (sim800l.available()) {
    char c = sim800l.read();
    Serial.write(c);
    delay(30); // Delay between characters to allow time for printing
  }
}

Few notes :- i have checked http post request with SIM800L and firebase.its working on firebase but iam getting problem in ngrok.And also i have tested ngrok using postman there also i getting proper response.
i tried enabling/disabling SSL.
Expecting suggestion in problem.
